# Displaying dateTime values with client time zone in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, client, richfaces

I have following code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myDataBean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="both" timeStyle="short" dateStyle="short" />
</h:outputText>
```

How can I display this dateTime element with client time zone in JSF (Richfaces)? I guess I should use timeZone attribute, but what should I specify as its value?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you won't know what the clients timezone is to set the timeZone attribute, the only way I can think of to do this is to convert the date in Javascript.

The `<f:convertDateTime>` converter defaults to UTC time.

```
<h:body onload="setTimezoneDates();" >
    <h:form id="myform">
      <h:outputText value="#{indexBean.today}" id="mydate">
        <f:convertDateTime type="both" timeStyle="short" dateStyle="medium" />
      </h:outputText>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And then use Javascript to convert your UTC date/time to the clients local date/time and replace it on the page.

```
function setTimezoneDates() {
    var strDate = document.getElementById("myform:mydate").innerHTML + " UTC";
    var d = new Date(strDate);                                      
    document.getElementById("myform:mydate").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString();
}
```

The output date still needs to be formated and there is probably a better way to do this in Javascript. Also note I had to set the `<f:convertDateTime>` dateStyle to medium for this to work in IE.

Comment: Thank you Mark,I already implemented it using javascript,but was looking for easier solution.Anyway your approach looks good,so I'll set your answer as accepted :)

Comment: Can you also explain me the reason of dateStyle="medium" for IE,cause it works fine for me with "short" value?

Comment: When I tried it in IE8 a short date like 6/28/11 was being converted to June 28, 1911 and not 2011.